# What is the rule for parenthesis in Scala method invocation?

Tags: scala

Isn't toList a method that converts something into a List?

If yes so why can't I use parenthesis with it? I must be missing something more fundamental here.

Here is the example:

```
val l = Array(1,2,3).toList // works fine

val l = Array(1,2,3).toList() // gives the error below
```

> Not enough arguments for method apply: (n: Int)Int in trait
>   LinearSeqOptimized. Unspecified value parameter n.

Comment: Found a similar question here which might help: [Confused about Scala method calling conventions, specifically the sum function on Seq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545027/confused-about-scala-method-calling-conventions-specifically-the-sum-function-on)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If a method is defined as

```
def toList = { /* something */ }
```

then it must be called as

```
object.toList
```

with no extra parentheses.  We say that this method has *zero parameter lists*.

We could also define a parameter list but put nothing in it:

```
def toList() = { /* something */ }
```

Now, we could call either of

```
object.toList()
object.toList
```

since Scala allows the shortcut of omitting parentheses on method calls.

As far as the JVM is concerned, there is no difference between the first definition ("zero parameter lists") and the second ("one empty parameter list").  But Scala maintains a distinction.  Whether this is a good idea or not is debatable, but the motivation might be clearer when you realize that we can also

```
def toList()() = { /* something */ }
```

which is known as *two empty parameter lists*, and then call any of

```
object.toList()()
object.toList()
object.toList
```

and now, if we were to convert this into a function, we would type it as

```
() => () => T   /* T is the return value of the something */
```

while the second definition would be

```
() => T
```

which is clearly different conceptually, even if practically you use it the same way (put in nothing and sooner or later get out a `T`).

Anyway, `toList` doesn't need any parameters, and the Scala standard is to leave off the parens unless the method changes the object itself (rather than just returning something), so it's `def toList` without any parens afterwards.  And thus you can only call it as `object.toList`.

Comment: Your explanation was great. It is hard for me to imagine the purpose of toList()(), but I will trust scala for now...

Comment: You forgot to mention that the extra parenthesis give an error because it's taken to be the `apply` method of the resulting `List`.

Comment: @Daniel - Good point.  But one could always fall back to ignoring parens if there was no apply, so that doesn't completely settle the issue.  I'll let people read your comment for that explanation :)

Comment: Is (,) same as ()() in function??

Comment: @JeffLee - No, `(,)` is invalid syntax.  `()()` is two empty parameter lists (which only Scala knows about; to anything else it just looks like a method with no parameters).

Comment: There is "def addInt( a:Int, b:Int ) : Int" in there.

Comment: @JeffLee - Did you mean `(a: Int, b: Int)` vs. `(a: Int)(b: Int)`?  Those are also not the same to Scala: one has one parameter list with two parameters, while the other has two parameter lists with one parameter each.  (In bytecode they would be implemented the same way, though; the JVM doesn't have an idea of multiple parameter lists.)

Comment: @JeffLee - The Scala library uses the feature extensively for implicits and for making things look like built-in aspects of the language.  For example, `list.foldLeft(0){ (sum, x) => sum + x }` is defined with two parameter lists (into which you put the initial value and function that incorporates another list element into the result).

Comment: The technique is called currying. It is also very useful when you don't have all parameters in hand. Say, you could have something like `sendMessage(msg: String)(timeout: Int)`. Then you might call `val sendMessage1sTimeout = sendMessage(1000)` and get a method that always times out after 1000 milliseconds. Then you can call `sendMessage1sTimeout("hello"); sendMessage1sTimeout("bye!)` for instance. This is particularly useful if a parameter is always going to be the same, or if your parameters are found at different places or points of execution.

Answer (score 21):

Your second line is actually interpreted as

```
val l = Array(1,2,3).toList.apply()
```

since `foo(x)` is "magic" syntax for `foo.apply(x)`.

That's why the complier complains about "not enough arguments", as the apply method on lists takes one argument.

Thus you can write e.g.:

```
scala> val i = Array(1, 2, 3).toList(1)
i: Int = 2
```

Comment: Perhaps that's why if the method does not have parameters, it is best not to declare it. Then you can use "chaining" as above.

Comment: But at the same time it can be hard to tell whether the (1) is the method's parameter OR is to be applied to the method result. :-|

Answer (score 5):

Let me answer from Scala coding style perspective.

Scala [style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#parentheses) says...

Omit empty parenthesis, only be used when the method in question has no side-effects (purely-functional). In other words, it would be acceptable to omit parentheses when calling queue.size, but not when calling println().

Religiously observing this convention will dramatically improve code readability and will make it much easier to understand at a glance the most basic operation of any given method. Resist the urge to omit parentheses simply to save two characters!

Answer (score 0):

11 Years later... The exception `Not enough arguments for method apply: (n: Int)Int in trait LinearSeqOptimized` message gives you the clue. Checking the docs for [LinearSeqOps.html#apply(n:Int):A](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/LinearSeqOps.html#apply(n:Int):A):

> `def apply(n: Int): A`
> Get the element at the specified index.

The `toList` in the `Array` **doesn't take any argument** [see [Array:toList docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Array.html#toList:List%5BA%5D)] and converts it to the `l: List[Int]`, which is a `LinearSeqOps` trait:

```
val l = Array(1,2,3).toList        // l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

There are many ways to call `apply(0)` in the list `l` to get the element at index `0`. ***They all do the same thing***:

```
var el1 = l.apply(0)               // el1: Int = 1
el1 = l(0)                         // el1: Int = 1
el1 = Array(1,2,3).toList.apply(0) // el1: Int = 1
el1 = Array(1,2,3).toList(0)       // el1: Int = 1
```

But if we don't provide the `Int` argument to `apply(n: Int)`, the code will fail with the given error. The same variations will ***all give the same error***:

```
el1 = Array(1,2,3).toList()        // not enough arguments for method apply: (n: Int)
el1 = Array(1,2,3).toList.apply()  // not enough arguments for method apply: (n: Int)
el1 = l.apply()                    // not enough arguments for method apply: (n: Int)
el1 = l()                          // not enough arguments for method apply: (n: Int)
```