# Why does my reassignment of a function value fail in Scala?

Tags: scala

In the following code I try to create a function value that takes no parameters and prints a message

```
trait Base {
  var onTrade = () => println("nothing")

  def run {
    onTrade
  }
}
```

In the following subclass I try to reassign the function value to print a different message

```
class BaseImpl extends Base {
  onTrade = () => {
    val price = 5
    println("trade price: " + price)
  }
  run
}
```

When I run BaseImpl nothing at all is printed to the console.  I'm expecting

```
trade price: 5
```

Why does my code fail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`onTrade` is a function, so you need to use parentheses in order to call it:

```
def run {
   onTrade()
}
```

---

#### Update

Method `run` most probably confuses you - you can call it even without parentheses. there is distinction between method and function. You can look at this SO question, it can be helpful:

[What is the rule for parenthesis in Scala method invocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643030/what-is-the-rule-for-parenthesis-in-scala-method-invocation)

Comment: Interesting thanks.  So what does onTrade actually do? (without the parentheses)

Comment: @deltanovember: literally nothing :) in this case method `run` just returns this function, but since you defined your method like this, return value would be just ignored (the actual return type of `run` is `Unit`)

Comment: I believe it just uses it like a normal variable if you do that. (please confirm someone better with Scala than I)

Comment: @Gunnar Hoffman: yes, it's treated as a value. You can pass it as an argument to other function/method or return it, but important thing is that this function would not be called/evaluated unless you call it explicitly with the help of parentheses.

Comment: Also, it's recommendable to always write your method return type.