# Play 2.0 parenthesis in template argument

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I am working with play 2.0 with java about a month and there is one thing that I really cannot understand. How templates are really work? What is the best way of passing params to them?

What's the difference between

```
@(name: String, value: String)
```

and

```
@(name: String)(value: String)
```

Is this only for convenience?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643030/what-is-the-rule-for-parenthesis-in-scala-method-invocation) question which lifts the veil of secrecy, but it doesn't tell which way I should choose.

Answer (score 4):

canonical example would be:

// main.scala.html

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)
....
```

// index.scala.html

```
@main("Foo Title") {
  <div>this content Html param passed in as a block {}</div>
}
```

with: `@(title: String, content: Html)`

the syntax is not quite as nice:

```
@main("Foo Title", {
  <div>...</div>
})
```

Comment: And one more question: are {} brackets for HTML only?

Comment: @AlexPovar in this case, well, yes, method argument is of type Html ;-) You can apply this anywhere, not just template layer, it's part of the Scala language itself; if you have def foo(a: Int)(b: Unit) = b, you can call it like foo(1) { println("bar") }

Answer (score 3):

In the first case you are passing multiple parameters to a function. In the second case you are using currying. According to Wikipedia:

> In mathematics and computer science, currying is the technique of transforming a function that takes multiple arguments (or an n-tuple of arguments) in such a way that it can be called as a chain of functions each with a single argument (partial application). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

What is best differs per use case.

Edit: note that templates are just Scala functions.

Comment: O, thanks. Too much functional programming for my head today :)