# Why doesn't "(0 to 9).reverse()" compile in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm a beginner in Scala.
As far as I know, the code `(0 to 9).reverse` has the same meaning with:

```
var range : Range = 0 to 9;
range.reverse
```

`range.reverse` means to call the reverse method of the `Range` object with no argument, and the brackets are omitted for short.

But when I wrote `range.reverse()`, a compile error came out:

```
error: not enough arguments for method apply: (idx: Int)Int in class Range.
Unspecified value parameter idx.
              range.reverse()
```

Why is that? Isn't `range.reverse` short for `range.reverse()`?

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643030/what-is-the-rule-for-parenthesis-in-scala-method-invocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val r = (0 to 9).reverse
```

Compiles and does what you expect.

When you add the paranethsis, the compiler thinks you are trying to call the `Range` class `apply` method, which takes a single index argument. You have not supplied any arguments so the compile fails.

Note:
method `reverse` defined at [Range.scala](http://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Range.scala#L1) like property (without '()'):

```
final override def reverse: Range = ...
```

Comment: Does it mean when I write `(0 to 9).reverse()`, the compiler thinks I am calling `((0 to 9).reverse)).apply()` ?

Comment: @WeiboLi - Yes it does, as the error message suggests.

Comment: `(0 to 9).reverse` is complete in itself because `reverse` method is defined without parentheses, and it returns a `Range` object. Therefore adding parentheses after that, invokes `Range.apply(...)`. Hence the compilation error.