# Play Framework template doesn't have Html type

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a template named `mainBody` with the form:

```
@(title: String)(html: Html, moreScripts: Html = Html(""))
```

I'm able to call this like

```
views.html.mainBody("All properties")(views.html.showProperties(list))
```

`views.html.showProperties()` is another template. I'm under the impression that templates are just functions that return `Html`. However, if I extend this to:

```
views.html.mainBody("All properties")(views.html.showProperties(list), views.html.showPropertiesScripts)
```

Where `views.html.showPropertiesScripts` is just a template with some HTML code, I get the error:

```
play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[type mismatch;
 found   : views.html.showPropertiesScripts.type
 required: play.twirl.api.Html]
        at play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27) ~[na:na]
        at play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.2.jar:na]
        at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$play$PlayReloader$$anon$$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReloader.scala:234) ~[na:na]
        at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$play$PlayReloader$$anon$$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReloader.scala:229) ~[na:na]
```

I don't understand this. Instead of the expected type `Html`, `views.html.showPropertiesScripts` is `views.html.showPropertiesScripts.type`? What is this and why is `views.html.showPropertiesScripts` not of type `Html` (like my other templates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing up "type" with "return type". Presumably is `views.html.showPropertiesScripts` is a template that doesn't take any parameters (it starts with `@()`). If this is the case, it does not have type `Html`, but rather, it's a class with a `def apply(): Html`, which is why when you "call" it with parentheses, it returns `Html`. You can think of it as having type `() => Html`. You should try:

```
views.html.mainBody("All properties")(views.html.showProperties(list), views.html.showPropertiesScripts())
```

You might be confused by the concept of [calling a method without a parameter list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6643085/807674). That can't work when dealing with `apply`, because if you leave the parameter list off, Scala interprets you as referring to the object itself, not the result of `apply`.

Answer (score 4):

Use this like `mainBody.scala.html`:

```
@(title: String, moreScripts: Html = Html(""))(html: Html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
      <title>@title</title>
      @moreScripts
    </head>
    <body>
       @html
    </body>
</html>
```

The view:

```
@(list: List[YourType])

@moreScripts = {
    <script>alert ('it works')</script>
}

@mainBody(title = "All properties", moreScripts = moreScripts) {
    @showProperties(list)
}
```

as `moreScripts` is optional you can skip it in the other view:

```
@(list: List[YourType])

@mainBody(title = "Other view") {
    @showProperties(list)
}
```

Comment: This works, and I like the style better than mine. However, could you please explain why this works and my original code does not?

Comment: Mike TBH I never analyzed Play's template engine, download sources if you're interested ;) General rule is in first brackets you declare all arguments of the view (mandatory and optional) and in second `Html` with content.

Comment: Much better. Works.