# Foo does not take parameters compile error in Scala?

Tags: scala, function, methods, traits

I have a compile error and I do not understand it.

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)

trait Rectangular {

  def topLeft: Point
  def bottomRight: Point

  def left = topLeft().x //Compile error occurring here
  def right = bottomRight.x
  def width = right - left

  // any many more concrete geometric methods.
 }
```

I am getting a compile error on the line where the third method is defined, saying "Point does not take parameters".

But I thought that you can invoke a function that does not take parameters with or without the `()`. As `topLeft` is just a method that has no parameters and has a return type of `Point`.

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643030/what-is-the-rule-for-parenthesis-in-scala-method-invocation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is described in Scala documentation:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html

Shortly, parenthesis is used to mark a method that has side-effects, so it's not allowed to call 0-arity (marked as) pure-method as side-effectful. See also:
[What is the rule for parenthesis in Scala method invocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643030/what-is-the-rule-for-parenthesis-in-scala-method-invocation)

It's also related to UAP (Uniform Access Principle) as method without `()` is interpreted as accessor, so you can implement it as a `val`:

```
trait A { def a: Int } //for some reason it works with parenthesis as well
class B extends A { val a: Int = 5 }
```

So here `someBInstance.a` vs `someATypedInstance.a` is better than `someBInstance.a` vs `someATypedInstance.a()`

Besides that, there is an example that explains why you can't use `def f = ...` with `()` - simply because `()` is also used as shortcut to call `apply`:

```
scala> class Z { def apply() = 5 }
defined class Z

scala> def f = new Z
f: Z

scala> f()
res87: Int = 5
```

Comment: As I understand your statement: `so it's not allowed to call pure-method as side-effectful`, I believe that it's mis-leading. The following works fine on the REPL - `def f(): Int = 55`. I take the word "not allowed" to mean that the compiler will enforce such a restriction.

Comment: @KevinMeredith I've added "marked as" specially for you; however, I meant what I meant if you write `def f(): Int = 5` that means your method is side-effectful, even if your current implementation is not, because you probably know that this `f` might be overridden with something not pure

Comment: Good point that marking a 0-arity `Unit`-returning method with `()` indicates side-effects (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7606214/409976 as a reference). My only point was (in case someone new to the language reads it) that it's simply a convention/style - the compiler does not enforce it.

Comment: @KevinMeredith except the case OP is talking about. I mean if you've got `def f = 5` (pure-method) compiler **enforces** you to always call it as pure, you can't call it as side-effectful `f()` - ":27: error: Int does not take parameters". Or shortly "it's not allowed to **call** (marked as) pure-method as side-effectful."  :))))

Comment: @KevinMeredith Btw, that is partially because scala uses `()` to call `apply` method as well, otherwise it would be hard to decide (in some cases like in my updated answer) how much `()` we need to call such method (but it could be solved with enforcing to use the whole `apply` in such cases, so it's probably is not a main reason)